# Time and Speed for csv Analyze (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, function, matplotlib

im trying to print and show, which t(time) are in speed=0 but nothing seems to work.

My goal is to show all the t(time) that there speed=0.

So when i have speed=0 to identify and show the specific t(time).

this is the script that i have wrote:

```py
N=0
tp=find_periods(time,vehicle_speed,N)
tp=np.array([])
i=0

def stop():
    for i in range(time):
        if(vehicle_speed[i-N:i]>0 and vehicle_speed[i:i+N]==0):
            tp=np.append(tp.time(i))
        if(vehicle_speed[i-N:i]==0 and vehicle_speed[i:i+N]>0):
            tp=np.append(tp.time(i))
    return tp
```

i tried to run this script but nothing worked.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Could you explain what *didn't work*? And please give debugging details.